# Stream video from my Windows VPS?

Tags: windows, windows-7, streaming, video

I run a Linux distro on my laptop and I have access to a remote Windows 7 desktop as a VPS. I have movies on that VPS. How would I go about streaming them?

Comment: Do you mean streaming or simply opening the files over the network and playing them using a player on your Linux laptop?

Comment: @music2myear I'd like to be able to stream.

Answer (score 0):

If it's streaming you want there are the following requirements:

Your streaming server needs to be able to transcode the media into a desired format, and you have to decide what sort of viewer/listener app you want to use on the receiving end.

If you have a Windows Media or iTunes media collection, both these software packages offer streaming capability. Windows Media Player supports the open DLNA standard. iTunes works best with another iTunes, and it's been a while since I've played around with Linux media players, but I'm pretty sure there's something out there than can connect to and stream from a shared iTunes media library.

The good news is that, if you're using either of these apps to stream, most of the hard work is done for you.

The MSDN blog has a step-by-step tutorial on how to stream to DLNA devices from Windows Media Player and Windows 7. You'll simply need to find a DLNA-compatible player for your viewer machine: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/e7/media-streaming-with-windows-7)

For the client app, XBMC is apparently compatible with the DLNA spec: http://xbmc.org/

**Update:**

You want LogMeIn Hamachi (https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/). It allows quick and configuration-free VPNs on demand. And it was free last time I checked. And it uses pretty decent encryption.

Comment: I don't have an iTunes collection, or a Windows Media Player connection (though I can make the latter). As far as I know, DLNA can't be broadcast on a non-local network - which is necessary for me as my Windows machine is several thousand kilometers away.

Comment: So you want an internet streaming station. Does it need to do video or just audio? is VPN an option? Also, you realize you'll need some sort of security so you're not just publicly broadcasting your media library.

Comment: Yes, an internet streaming station. VPN is... an option, at best. And yes, I do realize I'll need some security.